# Function that finds how many times n can be divided in half

Tags: python

Basically, I need a function that will divide n by two and return the number of times it can be done.

Coding so far:

```
def div(n):
    while n >= 0:
        n / 2
    return n
```

I know for a fact that I have to use the *while* loop, but I'm not confident in my third line of coding. What am I doing wrong?

Examples:

```
>>> div(4)
2
>>> div(7)
2
```

Comment: When you say that "n can be divided in half", do you mean that n/2 is an integer, or that n/2>=1? Your current code checks the latter, I believe.

Comment: You need to clarify if `n` is an integer, as otherwise `n` can be divided in half infinitely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/ does not perform assignment. Since you're returning n and not changing its value, I'd think you should start there. Your other hints are = and %.

Answer (score 29):

An integer **n** can be divided by **2**: `floor(log(n)/log(2))` times.

Comment: Or shorter: `floor(log(n, 2))`?

Answer (score 6):

(Note that I'm taking your examples as defining the expected behaviour of the function. As Tomas and Carl noted, the description isn't currently particularly clear.)

Recent versions of Python actually provide a [`bit_length()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) method on integers that makes it easy to find out the answer.

While that doesn't really help you with your homework question (it gives you the answer, but it doesn't help you understand *why* that's the answer), you can use it to create a reference function to compare with your actual answer:

```
def expected(n):
    return n.bit_length() - 1

>>> expected(4)
2
>>> expected(7)
2
>>> expected(33)
5
```

A few points to consider:

- your loop condition isn't correct, as repeated division will never reduce a value below zero. Given the example data, your terminating condition needs to be something different. Consider the answers you would expect for inputs of `0`, `1` or `2`.
- you need to be changing the value of `n` on each pass through the loop. Otherwise, your loop will never end.
- is `n` really the value you want to be returning? Perhaps there is something else you should be tracking as you go around the loop that will become your return value (a closer look at some of the other suggested answers should help with this point).

Answer (score 4):

Divisibility is defined as follows: one integer is divisible by another integer only if the result of that division is also an integer (not a fraction, no remainder).

See the [mathematical definition](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section02.02.html).

For example, 15 is divisible by 3 and 5 but not divisible by 2.
Given this definition, the highly-rated answer above, `floor(log(n)/log(2)` is completely wrong.

For example:
`3^10= 59,049`
This number is odd and only divisible by 3.
So `count-2-divisions(3^10) = 0`
The expression `floor(log(3^10)/log(2)=15`.

Comment: To clarify, given the definition of the function example div(7)=2, this answer is correct, but that isn't divisibility, it's something else.. In fact, it is exactly this, the logarithm, base 2, of a number. In terms of integer arithmetic, you are actually computing the power of two that is closest to, but less than the input number. In the example I gave above, that is 2^15, or 32,768.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two ways of doing it:

Bitwise operation ([shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Logical_shift)):

```
i = 8
result = 0
while i > 1:
    i = i >> 1
    result = result + 1
print result
```

and

```
i = 8
result = 0
while i > 1:
    i = i / 2
    result = result + 1
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that counts how many times a number n can be divided by another number p using the modulo:

```
>>> def dividible(n, p):
...     i = 0
...     while n%p==0:
...             n /= p
...             i += 1
...     return i
...
>>> dividible(16, 2)
4
>>> dividible(15, 2)
0
>>> dividible(8, 2)
3
>>> dividible(100, 2)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The internal function *divmod* is the key:

```
divmod(20,3)
>>> (6, 2)

divmod(20,3)[0]
>>> 6
```

Comment: Actually, the answer should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation is: How many times can you halve it (discarding remainder) until 0; assumes 32-bit integers?

```
def div(n):
    while n & (n - 1) > 0:
        n = n & (n - 1)
    a = [0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9]
    tmp = (n * 0x077CB531) % 0x100000000
    if tmp > 0xd0000000:
        tmp += -0x100000000
    return a[tmp >> 27]
```

Sample output:

```
   >>>print div(100)
   6
   >>>print div(1000)
   9
   >>>print div(1025)
   10
```

etc.